# TikZ: how to draw cyclic path around exactly one object?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a cyclic path (not necessarily a circle) around a given object in TikZ. Specifically, I want it to encompass exactly the black part and ignore to red part in the image below.[image]

Here is an example of what I have in mind: [image]

I tried using the fitting library but I can't get it to encompass only the black part and there is always extra space. I should note that I'm quite new to TikZ so this might be elementary. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw[red] (0,0) -- (0,2);
        \draw (0,2) --(0,3);
        \draw[red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0.8) (-1,2) (-2,4)};
        \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,2) (1,3) (2,4) (3,6)};
        \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(1,3) (1,4) (1.5,5)};
        \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(2,4) (3,4) (3.5,5)};
        \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,3) (0,4) (-1,5)};
        \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,4) (0,4.5) (0.3,5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that some manual work is inevitable.

I define a command `\mybox` to draw cyclic box from one point to another point. But following argument still need specified by your observation or some attempt to achieve what you want.

- `dir={<start point> to <target point>}` specify the start point and target point.
- `left=<out angle>:<in angle>:<distance>` specify the shape of the left curved line.
- `right=<out angle>:<in angle>:<distance>` is the same as `left`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  mybox/.cd,
  dir/.code args={(#1) to (#2)}{
    \def\mybox@start{#1}
    \def\mybox@target{#2}
  },
  left/.code args={#1:#2:#3}{
    \def\mybox@left@out{#1}
    \def\mybox@left@in{#2}
    \def\mybox@left@dist{#3}
  },
  right/.code args={#1:#2:#3}{
    \def\mybox@right@out{#1}
    \def\mybox@right@in{#2}
    \def\mybox@right@dist{#3}
  },
}
\newcommand\mybox[2][]{
  \def\mybox@left@out{45}
  \def\mybox@left@in{45}
  \def\mybox@right@out{45}
  \def\mybox@right@in{45}
  \def\mybox@left@dist{1cm}
  \def\mybox@right@dist{1cm}
  \pgfqkeys{/tikz/mybox}{#2}
  \draw[relative, line join=round,#1] (\mybox@start) to[out=\mybox@left@out, in=180+(-1)*(\mybox@left@in), distance=\mybox@left@dist] (\mybox@target)
  to[out=\mybox@right@in, in=180+(-1)*(\mybox@right@out), distance=\mybox@right@dist] (\mybox@start) -- cycle;
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (0,2);
  \draw (0,2) --(0,3);
  \draw[red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0.8) (-1,2) (-2,4)};
  \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,2) (1,3) (2,4) (3,6)};
  \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(1,3) (1,4) (1.5,5)};
  \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(2,4) (3,4) (3.5,5)};
  \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,3) (0,4) (-1,5)};
  \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,4) (0,4.5) (0.3,5)};
  \draw[red] (0, 0) to (1, 1);
  \mybox[dashed]{dir={(0, 2) to (3, 6)}, left=90:90:4cm, right=60:80:3cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]